# How to discard d3v4 drag events?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to build an draggable object with d3 and SVG.
The "target" object is an SVG G element that contains a "rect" as background, and SVG G elements as children with click events (like a grid).

I want to discard the events witch distances from the start drag point are lower than 11; because the "target" object has children that must receive click events when the drag distance is too short.

I tried to return 'true' or 'false' inside 'drag' function event to control when this event would be valid or not; but it is not working.

```
var x1 =0, y1 =0;
target.call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", function () {
        x1 =d3.event.x;
        y1 =d3.event.y;
        return true;
    })
    .on("drag", function () {
        var x2 = d3.event.x;
        var y2 = d3.event.y;
        var x = x2 - x1;
        var y = y2 - y1;
        var d2 = x * x + y * y;
        var distance = Math.sqrt(d2);
        return distance > 10;
    }).on("end", function () {
        console.log("end");
    })
);
```

Now, using drag, I found an additional problem:
A little movement on my mouse at the click moment, causes drag events instead of click event.

Is there any way to fix the problem without perform something like 'fake' clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my snippet does what you want, albeit not too sophisticated. Please note that click is not suppressed unless mouse movement exceeds threshold. Hope that makes the essence clear. Inspired by [this github issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/issues/28#issuecomment-246733166)‘s discussion.

```js
var target = d3.select('#test');
var x1 =0, y1 =0;
var threshold = 40;
var distanceReached = false;
target.call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", function () {
        x1 =d3.event.x;
        y1 =d3.event.y;
        distanceReached = false;
    })
    .on("drag", function () {
        var x2 = d3.event.x;
        var y2 = d3.event.y;
        var x = x2 - x1;
        var y = y2 - y1;
        var d2 = x * x + y * y;
        var distance = Math.sqrt(d2);
        distanceReached = distance > threshold;
        if (distanceReached) {
          target
            .style('left', x2 + 'px')
            .style('top',  y2 + 'px');
        }
    }).on("end", function () {
        if (distanceReached) {
          console.log('drag');
        } else {
          d3.select(window).on('click.drag', null);
          console.log('no drag');
        }
    })
);
target.on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
```

```css
#test { background:red; position:absolute; height:40px; width:40px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id='test' />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer works, but I'm using the click events in children objects, not in "target" object. I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: I had problems to test correctly this code. I cleaned my project and tried again and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Did you have to modify the code to run with children objects?

Comment: No, I didn't. It didn't necessary perform changes.